# Force incremental crawl

Tags: sharepoint-2010, search

I am plannning a Search Server 2010 and a MS SQL 2012. Can I be sure that when someone updates a record and searches for it immediately after that, the query will return the new record as well?

If it will be only indexed at the next scheduled time, is it possible to force an incremental crawl in a Search Server every time someone changes content? I see I can set the crawl period to 1 minute but I need it faster than that - 10 seconds or less.

What are the effects to the server if I have only a few records updated for these 10 seconds? How can I be sure that when someone updates a record and searches for it, the query will return it?

Comment: Why you need that? Basically if you need immediately, DO NOT USE SEARCH SERVER, use SQL statements.

Comment: Tell us more about your requirements. I don't think a user will upload something, and then search for it immediately? There must be another reason?

Comment: The customer needs a message board. He will also have a list of predefined keywords (similar to twitter hashtags). When someone types the message and starts one of the keywords, I need to be able to show a list of the keywords that start with the letters the user typed so far. The functionality resembles a lot the intellisense in VS.NET or Google search.